# Does a memory_limit set in included script apply to a complete request?

Tags: php, memory, process, include

When I set `ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');` in an included script, does this apply to the complete request, in which this script is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update re acmatos' comment:** Yes, if you call `set_memory_limit` in a child include, it will apply to the whole script. An include is not a separate process of any kind, but simply another place for the PHP interpreter to look for code. To the interpreter, there is *one* script, no matter how many files you include.

The only exception is when you include a file using a `http://` URL. That is treated like a remote request even though it points on localhost. For that, a new request is started to parse that file, a new PHP process is started, which has its own memory limit. This practice is highly unusual though.

**Old answer:**

I'm not sure what you mean by "complete request" in this context, but the answer is probably no. The memory limit applies to the PHP script only and memory allocated/used by it. It does  not apply to any external binaries called using `exec()` for example.

Comment: I think he is including a .php script inside another and the child one has the `ini_set`. So the question is if the included `ini_set` will also apply to the parent script. If that's the case think "yes" but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Labuschin you're welcome. Note however that changing the memory limit inside the script is usually disabled on shared hosting, so it may not have any effect at all.

Comment: @Artefacto no source necessary IMO: Requesting a resource like `http://domain.com/script.php` will always start a separate http request, which will spawn a separate PHP process. There's no way for it to behave differently, is there? Things would be different for *clear text PHP source code* emitted by such an include and *interpreted* inside the including script instance. That would be executed in the script's context. This would be doubly unusual though, and a highly dangerous practice so I'm not really taking it into consideration.

Comment: Oh, OK, I thought you referring to the second case.